# How to change config variable names in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a standalone app with spring boot. I want it read properties file provided by user but i want to customize command line API. i don't want `--spring.config.location=...` instead i would like `--config=...`. does spring boot support this kind of customization? how can i achieve this?

Comment: You can achive it by defining your custom properties and then using a placholder to configure spring properties with your properties. Let's say that you have a property spring.foo.bar, then you're adding your own property foo.bar which you can configure, and you're assiging your property to a spring one spring.foo.bar=${foo.bar}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to `--config` instead of `--spring.config.location=...` but it comes with a cost.

Assume *C:/temp/myconfig.properties*

```
my.message = Hello outside
```

Use your own *ConfigurationProperties*

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("${config}")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
class ApplicProps {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

then you should be able to start your application like:

`java -jar your_application.jar --config=file:C:/temp/myconfig.properties`

---

An other way to do this is to play with the command line option arguments.
And because `--config` comes in as an argument you could start you application like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // allowed arguments
        String[] acceptedArgs = new String[1];
        for (String arg: args) {
            if(arg.startsWith("--config")){
                // convert --config to the default --spring.config.location
                acceptedArgs[0] = arg.replace("--config","--spring.config.location");
            }
        }

        SpringApplication.run(YourApp.class, acceptedArgs); // <-- use acceptedArgs
    }
```